# Gain knob on Sound Devices MixPre moving during recording

Tags: field-recording, recording, portable-recorder, location-recording

I use the Sound Devices MixPre-D to do field recording and I'm finding that one of the gain knobs often gets moved while I'm out recording.  It seems to be just a touch loose compared to the other gain control, though not very!  I've tried removing the knob and tightening but this doesn't help.

I use it in a fishing tackle bag (lots of useful pockets) and moved it in to one of the more secure pockets and have taped cardboard over top of the gain knobs.  This seems to help but is really irritating to have to undo the taped cardboard to change gain levels.

I am often walking while record - hence why the Mix-Pre moves around in my bag.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well the easiest and most expensive answer is buy a bag designed for the mixpre. Petrol has one: http://cvp.com/index.php?t=product/petrol_ps607

Cheers,
Arnoud